# EF Common file table structure

Tags: sql, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, database-normalization

Personel Table

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC |
| 2 | DEF |

Car Table

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | X Car |
| 2 | Y Car |

Image&Document Table

| Id | Path | EntityId | EntityName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Car-1.Jpg | 1 | Car |
| 2 | Person1.Jpg | 1 | Personal |
| 3 | Car-3.Jpg | 3 | Car |

I want to create a sustainable and evolving common document table for all my assets.
Would it be appropriate to set up the structure as above in EF?
Does it make it harder for me to use the Include(Join) construct?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Comment: Rearranging tables between designs for supertypes/subtypes is not DB normalization (in either of its senses of normalization to a 1NF or to higher NFs).

Comment: Please ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)  [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461) [ask] [Help]